# Using 'cat' from local file to remote file while ssh'd into server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ssh

If my file `something.txt` is on a local client and I am ssh'd into a remote server, can I not:

`cat /path/on/local/client/something.txt >> /path/on/server`

I was able to do what I wanted via:

`cat something.txt | ssh username@server "cat > /path/on/server"`

But that was outside of server on client. Would like to have remained in server. Is `scp` required first to get the file onto the server?

Comment: *"can I not..."* -- No, you cannot.  You need a NFS mount to do something like that, instead of a remote login.

Comment: Yes SCP is required to transfer the file as you have already seen. That is the "file transfer" portion of SSH.